# mercurial graphlog color and style

Tags: mercurial

my hgrc:

```
[ui]
style=compact

[extensions]
graphlog=
color=
```

but hg glog has no color. and, how many style for hg log, help, man can't get any information.

Comment: which hg version in which shell in what terminal on what operating system?

Comment: This issue was reported here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2866

Answer (score 7):

The four command line styles available are:

- default
- compact
- changelog -- looks like a Gnu-style changelog file
- xml -- provides log data as an XML structure

This is found by looking inside Mercurial's template's directory, which on my system ends up in usr/share/mercurial/templates but may differ on arch.

With mercurial 1.6.4 I do get color in `glog` but only if I"m using the default style.  The `compact` style doesn't seem to have color codes.

Comment: do you means that latest version has fix this problem?

Comment: No, I said that even in the latest version there's no color in the compact version of glog.  If you want color use the default style.